# Check Textbox with an Array Variable SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, variables

I'm wanting to check when the keyboard is dismissed, is it possible to check using

```
if firstName.text?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(CheckArrayOfText) != nil
```

to check against a array variable like

```
var CheckArrayOfText:Array = [Word, Paragraph, Sentence]
```

I already know how to check it against just a string of text but not aginst a variable of an array by using

```
if firstName.text?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("STRING") != nil
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You should probably give `CheckArrayOfText` a better name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to see if the textfield contains any of the elements of the array. In that case, try:

```
let firstNameText = firstName.text?.lowercaseString
let result = CheckArrayOfText.contains(where: { firstNameText.rangeOfString($0) != nil })
```